# What is the correct REST call for a REST services with 3 parameters?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8 I created a view (`viewrestname`) which lists 3 fields (userid/key1/key2). I added a rest service (let's say `\Rests`) to this.
Then I added a contentual field `userid` to it.

When I now call

```
\Rests\viewrestname\1
```

I get the correct JSON back.

When I add the other two fields as contextual filters and call

```
\Rests\viewrestname\1\key1 or
\Rests\viewrestname\1\key1\key2
```

I get a *page not found* error.

My questions:

1. How to change the rest call to e.g.

   `\Rests\viewrestname?userid=<>?key1=<>?key2`

   or
2. How to get this call running:

   `\Rests\viewrestname\1\14\15`

   where 14 is key1 and 15 is key2

Note: When I use the preview button in the view it is working correct.